# Angular2 router canActivate no provider for false

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So my code looks like this:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { 'path': '', redirectTo: '/jobs', terminal: true, canActivate: [tokenNotExpired()]  },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [!tokenNotExpired()] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  ...WihRoutes
];
```

Whenever I try navigating to "account", the routing fails as it should, but for some reason it also gives the following console error:

> browser_adapter.ts:82 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No
>   provider for false!BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:82BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @
>   browser_adapter.ts:93ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:58(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:374schedulerFn @
>   async.ts:148SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @
>   Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @
>   Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.ts:133onError @ ng_zone.ts:142onHandleError @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:95ZoneDelegate.handleError @
>   zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @
>   zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:426 browser_adapter.ts:82
>   STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:82ExceptionHandler.call @
>   exception_handler.ts:61(anonymous function) @
>   application_ref.ts:374schedulerFn @
>   async.ts:148SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @
>   Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @
>   Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.ts:133onError @ ng_zone.ts:142onHandleError @
>   ng_zone_impl.ts:95ZoneDelegate.handleError @
>   zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @
>   zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:426 browser_adapter.ts:82 Error: Uncaught (in promise): No
>   provider for false!
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
>       at zone.js:515
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
>       at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.ts:72)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
>       at zone.js:571
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.ts:61)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)

Also pic of error because formatting was awful.
[image: Stacktrace]

I have no clue as to why this happens - anybody else?

Comment: How does `tokenNotExpired()` look like?

Comment: Returns true / false, nothing else. Same thing happens if I write canActivate: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed to `canActivate: [!tokenNotExpired()]` needs to be a provider. `!tokenNotExpired()` is not a valid provider.

```
canActivate: ['tokenExpired']
canActivate: ['!tokenExpired']
```

and provide in bootstrap or with `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  {provide: 'tokenExpired', useValue: (a: any, b: any) => tokenExpired()}
  {provide: '!tokenExpired', useValue: (a: any, b: any) => !tokenExpired()}
]);
```

Comment: As far as I know, passing a plain false to canActivate doesn't need a provider? If it is, I'd love some docs where it states something like it.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard shows how to provide an guard. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b42411ba1f6d0f989e5fa846524d3d9e2425e834/modules/%40angular/router/test/router.spec.ts#L849 shows how to provide always false. I'd rather see docs that explain that what you showed in your question is supposed to work.

Comment: I was just going off of this:A guard's return value controls the router's behavior:

if it returns true, the navigation process continues
if it returns false, the navigation process stops and the user stays put

Comment: But what you add to `canActivate: [...]` at the route is only a provider for a guard, not a guard. You might use `useValue: false`, but `canActivate: [false']` won't work.

Comment: Fab, thanks. Read the source for angular2-jwt, and seems like it returns true/undefined, and not false for some reason. Got an understanding of it now, cheers!